# Launching the iPhone dialler but with contact name instead of number

Tags: iphone

I am trying to create a simple dialler for my iPhone. I know that there is no way of doing this unless I launch the native dialler using ://tel... I do not have a problem with this but the question is, is there a way to send a name along with the number I want to dial to the dialler so that what appears in the dialler entry field would be a name rather than a number? so instead of showing "+441234567890" on the dialer I want to show "Test Number".

In case this is not acceptable could I do something similar given that the contact is in the iPhone contacts list? so I will send to the dialer a reference or something to the contact i want to dial?

Cheers
Abolfoooud

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have the number +123456789 In my contact list, and an app dials it, then it will be replaced with the contact name, just as if you typed it in instead of calling from the contact.

If the user adds a contact with the number, as prompted by your app, then your idea may work, pending on the user's actions.